# VS2012 Web Forms Project breaks after upgrading JQuery to V 1.8.1

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, juice-ui

I created a web Forms project using Visual Studio 2012 and then upgraded JQuery library to 1.8.1 using nuget package manager.  When I try to run the project, I get the following error.  Any ideas?

```
> Unhandled exception at line 6, column 2 in
> http://localhost:49618/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23.js
> 
> 0x800a1391 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined
```

I just noticed that this error occurs only with IE9, but not with Chrome or Firefox browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured this out.  My project also contains a [JuiceUI](http://juiceui.com/) package, and it seems to be not compatible with latest version of JQuery.  I uninstalled this package and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error which was due to a mistmatch between the jquery and jquery-ui versions. Upgrading to the latest release of jquery solved it: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Current_Release

Comment: See updated answer - there was a thread on another forum that pointed me to the issue, but I can't google it up now.